# Custom Data for Custom Events in HockeyApp

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp, custom-events

**Context**: HockeyApp can track custom events which is a feature that is currently available via the Preseason program. There are limitations to custom events including

> a limit of 300 unique event names per app per week.

An event can be tracked by calling a specific method such as

```
HockeyApp.Metrics.MetricsManager.TrackEvent("MyEventName");
```

**Question**: We've got the challenge that we need to log custom data per event such as time stamp information. How to achieve this?

**Background**: we use Application Insights currently and log performance information with events such as how long it took to execute a ask. We look for a solution (or workaround) using HockeyApp.

Comment: We use HockeyApp for crash data only and give up using their custom events (too limiting, no analytics, big-data export, raw export, realtime access...) They have a **long way** to go to complete with everyone else. When 24 hours for event analytics is fine, we use Google's Firebase as they can also dump to BigQuery and offer raw exports, for real-time monitoring we use https-based GETs with encoded params that carry all the data for each event against an Azure web server that does nothing other then allowing us to stream the server logs for tracing 5m+ events a day (we track EVERYTHING ;-)

Comment: Great feedback. Thank you @SushiHangover!

Comment: @SushiHangover HockeyApp does support big-data export to Application Insights.

Comment: @Kerni I know, that is why we used Firebase: *"we use Google's Firebase as they can also dump to BigQuery"* Personally the difference between Application Insights and Google's BigQuery is night and day. It just depends upon your devops requirements, for that project ours exceeded what A.I. could provide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API [documentation on github](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Xamarin) shows it has the ability to add properties and measurements to the event:

```
HockeyApp.MetricsManager.TrackEvent("Custom Event",
                            new Dictionary<string, string> { { "property", "value" } },
                            new Dictionary<string, double> { { "time", 1.0 } })
```

The even names are limited but the [number of times an event can fire is not](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/general-account-management-2/getting-started-with-custom-events-public-preview#limits).

Comment: Wow, that appears to be a feature that must have been introduced between asking the question and now. Thank you! I will check this this.

Comment: Are properties and measurements visible also from HockeyApp or only if you make the integration with Azure Application Insight?

Comment: @DanieleD. looks like the latter, see https://martynnw.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/tracking-custom-events-with-xamarin-hockeyapp-and-azure-application-insights/#comment-56